# Adding DBContext Service to program.cs in Worker Project

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Fairly new to all this, so apologies if I am doing anything stupid.

I am trying to implement a worker project with communication to a local SQL Server Express database I have setup.

I am storing the connection string in my `AppSettings.Json` as shown below

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DBConnection": "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=TwitterTesting;Trusted_Connection=True;"
  }
}
```

I then have a `DBContext.cs` file which stores the structure of my database. At the moment I only have one table 'tweets'.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WorkerService1.Entities;

namespace WorkerService1
{
    public class DataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<tweets> tweets { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`Tweets.cs` has the column structure only.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace WorkerService1
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddDbContextPool<DataContext>(
                        options => options.UseSqlServer(hostContext.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection"))
                    );
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                });
    }
}
```

Above is my `program.cs` file where I am trying to add the implementation of the `DBContext`, but I am getting the following error upon compilation:

> System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: WorkerService1.Worker': Cannot consume scoped service 'WorkerService1.DataContext' from singleton 'Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostedService'.)

My understanding from looking online it is something to do with dependency injection, but I am really confused with what I need to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Where you define WorkerService1.DataContext and how add it to DI?

Comment: @SaeedEsmaeelinejad Apologies, I am not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/scoped-service?pivots=dotnet-6-0

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is that you're trying to create a `Scoped` service of your DbContext, but the class that's going to use it (`Worker`) is a `Singleton` class - note the following two lines.

```
services.AddDbContextPool<DataContext>( /*omitted*/ );
services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
```

While neither of these explicitly state *how* the service is being added to DI, `AddHostedService<Worker>` is registering `Worker` class as a singleton - only one instance of `Worker` will be created, ever. `AddDbContextPool<DataContext>` is registering `DataContext` as a scoped service - one that should be constructed every time a scope is created in which `DataContext` is asked for.

The problem is that if `Worker` asks for `DataContext` in the constructor, you'll get a single `DataContext` that will live for the duration of the the `Worker` - which is going to be forever, because `Worker` is a singleton.

To get a scoped `DataContext` in your `Worker` class, you'll need to get the service provider from DI and create a scope each time your `Worker` iterates in a main method - for example:

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.Management.Infrastructure.Options;
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
private readonly ILogger<Worker> _logger;
private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;

public Worker (ILogger<Worker> logger, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
{
    _logger = logger;
    _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
}
protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
{
    while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        _logger.Log("Creating scope to get a new DataContext.");
        // this will give us a scoped service
        using var scope = _serviceProvider.CreateScope();
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        // if DataContext were configured as singleton through AddSingleton<DataContext> 
        // in ConfigureServices, this would always be the same instance. Since it's added 
        // as Scoped, we'll get the same instance every time we ask for the service from 
        // our scope but each time we create a new scope it'll be a new instance.
        var context = services.GetService<DataContext>();
        // do something with context
        // we can validate that within our scope it's always the same object reference:
        _logger.Log("Get scoped service multiple times yields the same reference: {0}", object.ReferenceEquals(context, services.GetService<DataContext>());
        context.Dispose();
    }
}
```

For additional information, check out the following page - particularly paying heed to mentions of "Scoped", "Transient", and "Singleton".
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-5.0

Comment: Are you saying that if I have `services.AddHostedService<HardWorker>()` that is inheriting `class HardWorker : BackgroundService`, then I can't inject a context using the usual `service.AddDbContext<SomeContext>(...)`?

Comment: @KonradViltersten That is correct, if you just use `AddDbContext` and `AddHostedService` you’ll get the scope exception seen in OP. You must inject `IServiceProvider` and use that to get the db context if you want to use DbContext from a singleton service - I demonstrated how to do this in my response.

Comment: I'm curious - wouldn't it be a good idea to move out the scope and service provider outside the while loop? Or is there a gain to re-obtain those for each iteration? Also, I wonder if we need dispose of the context at the end. Somehow, I thought that when `scope` get out of... well... scope, then it's disposed **together** with the services and contexts referred from it. Please share your thoughts on this.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Disposing of the scope should dispose of the services it has created. You could create your scope outside of the `while` loop, but in doing so you lose any benefit it has for being a scoped service. I tend to figure that starting each loop in a "clean state" is better and that way if there's some kind of wait or interval, etc., you aren't holding unneeded resources. However YMMV and it is, like all things, dependent on your use case, so do what you find works best!

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. The *YMMV* part helped me realize that **both** strategies are correct, so I have not to worry: it's not *pick the right one* but rather *pick the right one **in this case***.